# Continuing a transaction after primary key violation error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, transactions, constraints

I am doing a bulk insert of records into a database from a log file. Occasionally (~1 row out of every thousand) one of the rows violates the primary key and causes the transaction to fail. Currently, the user has to manually go through the file that caused the failure and remove the offending row before attempting to re-import. Given that there are hundreds of these files to import it is impractical.

**My question:** How can I skip the insertion of records that will violate the primary key constraint, without having to do a `SELECT` statement before each row to see if it already exists?

*Note: I am aware of the very similar question [#1054695](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054695/continue-after-primary-key-violation-error), but it appears to be a SQL Server specific answer and I am using PostgreSQL (importing via Python/psycopg2).*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also use SAVEPOINTs in a transaction.

Pythonish pseudocode is illustrate from the application side:

```
database.execute("BEGIN")
foreach data_row in input_data_dictionary:
    database.execute("SAVEPOINT bulk_savepoint")
    try:
        database.execute("INSERT", table, data_row)
    except:
        database.execute("ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT bulk_savepoint")
        log_error(data_row)
        error_count = error_count + 1
    else:
        database.execute("RELEASE SAVEPOINT bulk_savepoint")

if error_count > error_threshold:
    database.execute("ROLLBACK")
else:
    database.execute("COMMIT")
```

Edit:  Here's an actual example of this in action in psql based on a slight variation of the example in the documentation (SQL statements prefixed by ">"):

```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (test_field INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "table1_pkey" for table "table1"
CREATE TABLE

> BEGIN;
BEGIN
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1);
INSERT 0 1
> SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
SAVEPOINT
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table1_pkey"
> ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
ROLLBACK
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3);
INSERT 0 1
> COMMIT;
COMMIT
> SELECT * FROM table1;  
 test_field 
------------
          1
          3
(2 rows)
```

Note that the value 3 was inserted after the error, but still inside the same transaction!

The documentation for SAVEPOINT is at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-savepoint.html.

Comment: That's not going to work, when an error happens, the transaction is aborted and rollbacked. You need an exception handler inside the database.

Query failed: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Comment: Yes it will.  That's the whole point of SAVEPOINTs.  I've edited my answer in order to give a concrete example.

Comment: ----edit----

Sorry, I was wrong... shame on me ;) It works fine, you're right.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am adding millions of rows in a single transaction - what are the performance implications of adding millions of savepoints during a transaction (even if it is overwritten each successful row)?

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance impact.  If you are already running this without the savepoints, I would think it wouldn't be too difficult to add them in and test.  Even if there is a performance impact per insert, you can load the data in "blocks" of records to minimize savepoints, only rolling back and handling in detail the blocks that fail.

Also, the documentation states that the savepoints with the same name are not destroyed, only masked by the more recent one, so you might want to add a RELEASE SAVEPOINT <name> after the INSERT in the try block in my example.

Comment: @MatthewWood, What if you anticipate the number of errors to be more than the number of inserts?

Comment: @Jeff, If it were me, I would load the entire new file into a temporary table then do a single insert of all records from the temp table where the PK does not exist in the target table.  There are several ways this can be done (NOT IN, LEFT JOIN, EXCEPT), so an efficient method should be possible depending on the volume of data.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a stored procedure to catch the exceptions on your unique violations. Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_insert(i_foo text, i_bar text)
  RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
begin   
    insert into foo(x, y) values(i_foo, i_bar);
    exception
        when unique_violation THEN -- nothing

    return true;
end;
$BODY$;

SELECT my_insert('value 1','another value');
```

Comment: It is always better to log your exceptions.. you can modify the exception blog to log it and still continue.

Comment: You can let the function log the exceptions, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `rollback` to the transaction or a rollback to a save point just before the code that raises the exception (cr is the cursor):

```
name = uuid.uuid1().hex
cr.execute('SAVEPOINT "%s"' % name)
try:
    # your failing query goes here
except Exception:
    cr.execute('ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT "%s"' % name)
    # your alternative code goes here 
else:
    cr.execute('RELEASE SAVEPOINT "%s"' % name)
```

This code assumes there is running transaction, otherwise you would not receive that error message.

Django postgresql backend [creates cursors](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cecc079168e8669138728d31611ff3a1e7eb3a9f/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py#L213) directly from [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html). Maybe in the future they make a proxy class for the Django cursor, similar to the [cursor of odoo](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/fc2e80cb4bcc450762c7ac5cb82a3e2d88062b38/odoo/sql_db.py#L61). They extend the cursor with the [following code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/fc2e80cb4bcc450762c7ac5cb82a3e2d88062b38/odoo/sql_db.py#L396) (self is the cursor):

```
@contextmanager
@check
def savepoint(self):
    """context manager entering in a new savepoint"""
    name = uuid.uuid1().hex
    self.execute('SAVEPOINT "%s"' % name)
    try:
        yield
    except Exception:
        self.execute('ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT "%s"' % name)
        raise
    else:
        self.execute('RELEASE SAVEPOINT "%s"' % name)
```

That way the context makes your code easier, it will be:

```
try:
    with cr.savepoint():
        # your failing query goes here
except Exception:
    # your alternative code goes here
```

and the code is more readable, because the transaction stuff is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use SSIS and have the failed rows take a differnt path than the successful ones.

SInce you are usinga differnt database can you bulk insert the files to a staging table and then use SQL code to select only those records which do not have an exisitng id?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by SSIS?

Comment: SSIS is the data import tool that comes with SQL Server. I didn't catch that you are using postgre. It can still do the job for postgre but I'm not sure how you would get it as I don't think it comes with the free version of SQL Server.