# django.db.utils.DatabaseError: out of shared memory

Tags: django, debugging, postgresql, django-orm

I'm written a script to load some objects into a Django database using the Django ORM. The underlying database is Postgres.

After running happily for a while, the script fails with this error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: out of shared memory
HINT: You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
```

I'm guessing this is a problem with my script's efficiency, rather than the database settings.

The script iterates over a CSV file, and create a database object for every row in the CSV file. Typically there are a couple thousand objects to create. I've read [some background material on database efficiency in Django](http://www.slideshare.net/OReillyOSCON/unbreaking-your-django-application). I can rule out some mistakes - I'm not iterating over a queryset, or using `__in` queries or `OFFSET`.

But I do have quite a lot of indexes on fields in my database, and I guess that each time I create and save an object, Django has to update all the indexes. I have six indexes on the `StoreItem` fields, for example.

```
for item in csv_rows: 
  s, created = StoreItem.objects.get_or_create(display_url=item['display_url'], \
         retailer_img_url=item['retailer_img_url'],store=store_obj)
  s.name = item['name']
  s.description = item['description']
  s.affiliate = item['affiliate']
  ... more stuff
  s.save()
```

Two questions:

1. Is it possible that updating the database indexes could cause this error?
2. How can I debug if this is the case?

Comment: How many lines in a CSV are we talking about here?

Comment: Not many. Typically a few thousand.

Comment: I think indexes may be the cause... I just hit this error after adding more indexes to my tables...

Answer (score 3):

I have had a quick google and there are a couple of resources to look at:

1. [postgresql: out of shared memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132533/postgresql-out-of-shared-memory)
2. http://www.databasesoup.com/2012/06/postgresqlconf-maxlockspertransaction.html

This quotes is taken from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-locks.html

> max_locks_per_transaction (integer)
>
> The shared lock table tracks locks on max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions) objects (e.g., tables);
> hence, no more than this many distinct objects can be locked at any
> one time. This parameter controls the average number of object locks
> allocated for each transaction; individual transactions can lock more
> objects as long as the locks of all transactions fit in the lock
> table. This is not the number of rows that can be locked; that value
> is unlimited. The default, 64, has historically proven sufficient, but
> you might need to raise this value if you have clients that touch many
> different tables in a single transaction. This parameter can only be
> set at server start.
>
> Increasing this parameter might cause PostgreSQL to request more System V shared memory than your operating system's default
> configuration allows. See Section 17.4.1 for information on how to
> adjust those parameters, if necessary.
>
> When running a standby server, you must set this parameter to the same or higher value than on the master server. Otherwise, queries
> will not be allowed in the standby server.

So, it looks like you should check the default value of max_locks_per_transaction to check its set to a sensible value

Likewise, if you are using a default install of postgres then you should probably check all the other defaults as in some instances defaults can be set too low.